# От n до 0 на Си

Tags: c, рекурсия

Возникла проблема с написанием программы , которая бы выводила в

консоль числа в убывающем порядке от n до 0,

не используя операторы: if, ?:, switch, for,

while, do while, goto, <, >, <=, >=, !=, ==.

Comment: Ну допустим мы тут напишем, а потом что?

Comment: Чего парня заминусовали? Не такая уж плохая задачка. Топикстартер есть какие-то идеи что вообще можно использовать? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство логических операторов состоит в том, что они вычисляются по короткой схеме. Т.е. вычисление прекращается, когда стал известен результат.

Отсюда простейшая функция

```
int run(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return n && run(n - 1);
}

run(5);
```

Оператор

```
return n && run(n - 1);
```

читается как

```
return (n != 0) && (run(n - 1) != 0);
```

На последней итерации `n==0`, общий результат уже известен (`false`) и следующий вызов `run(n - 1)` не производится